# how to implement SMS sending in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sms

I need to have some idea (some code) to implement sms sending on mobile phones using windows application developed in visual basic 2010.
I have done with email sending, but i have no idea about sms sending.

I have done sms sending using free API's in PHP. But in vb.net I want to do it without APIs..**(I want to connect my mobille to my application)**

So any knowledgeable comment will be big help for me...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand what your saying. But I think you simply want to send an SMS message in your VB .Net application. For example I think what your asking is how to send an SMS message from your VB .Net application to another phone number. If that is the case you should do the same as you would when sending E-Mails with VB .Net and utilize the SMS gateways. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Remember only one phone number can exist so sending an sms message to 8005551212@vzwpix.com and 8005551212@pm.sprint.com will only will work. Only one message will be recieved because the other SMS gateways don't have a number for it. So try creating a list of all the SMS gateways and having the the user type their number in and then sending the message out with the users entered number@gateway.com will work.

```
    'Now lets test the E-Mail functionality on our phone gap site. This section does just that.
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim mailfrom As String
    Dim mailto As String

    mailfrom = lblAddress.Text
    mailto = tbNumber.Text

    email.To.Add(mailto)
    email.From = New MailAddress(mailfrom)
    email.Body = tbmsgBody.Text

    Dim sendserver As String

    sendserver = lblSMTP.Text
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(sendserver)
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String

    username = lblUName.Text
    password = lblPW.Text

    If lblSSL.Text = "Yes" Then
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    Else : SMTP.EnableSsl = False
    End If

    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    Dim portnum As String

    portnum = lblPort.Text
    SMTP.Port = portnum
    SMTP.Send(email)
    MessageBox.Show("Message Sent")
ElseIf cbAction.Visible = True And cbAction.Text = "Send" And tbSubject.Visible = False Then
    'The idea behind this section is mainly to use the SMS Gateways and using the same E-Mail Form. Since their will only always be just one phone. We can try to send the same message to all of of the SMS gateways for that number. Obviously only one message will ever be recieved and the sender of the message will get a whole bunch of delivery failure messages. But at least one will get to the actual phone number.
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim mailfrom As String
    Dim mailto As String

    mailfrom = lblAddress.Text
    mailto = tbNumber.Text
    'Now lets add our SMS Gateways
    'Since this is a SMS and MMS portion their will be no need to add a subject feild.
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@myboostmobile.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@vtext.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.airfiremobile.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@msg.acsalaska.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.alltelwireless.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mms.alltelwireless.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@message.Alltel.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@text.wireless.alltel.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mms.alltel.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@paging.acswireless.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@txt.att.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mmode.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mms.att.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@txt.att.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cingularme.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mobile.mycingular.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@page.att.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.smartmessagingsuite.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@bellsouth.cl")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.bluecell.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mms.myblueworks.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cellcom.quiktxt.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@csouth1.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cwemail.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.cvalley.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cingular.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cingular.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mobile.mycingular.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cingulartext.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.cleartalk.us")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.mycricket.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mms.mycricket.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@cspire1.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@sms.edgewireless.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@SMS.elementmobile.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mobile.gci.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@gscsms.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@hawaii.sprintpcs.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@myhelio.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@iwirelesshometext.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mobile.kajeet.net")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@text.longlines.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@mymetropcs.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@messaging.sprintpcs.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@pm.sprint.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@messaging.nextel.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@page.nextel.com")
    email.Bcc.Add(mailto + "@tmomail.net")
    email.From = New MailAddress(mailfrom)
    email.Subject = tbSubject.Text
    email.Body = tbmsgBody.Text

    Dim sendserver As String

    sendserver = lblSMTP.Text
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(sendserver)
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String

    username = lblUName.Text
    password = lblPW.Text

    If lblSSL.Text = "Yes" Then
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    Else : SMTP.EnableSsl = False
    End If

    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    Dim portnum As String

    portnum = lblPort.Text
    SMTP.Port = portnum
    SMTP.Send(email)
    MessageBox.Show("Message Sent")
```

You can view entire source code on https://github.com/LinuxPhreak/PhoneGap-Emulators

Comment: I want to connect SIM to computer any way..then want to perform sms sending from it by using GUI designed in vb.net........Do u have any working example ??

Comment: Actually no I miss understood you. The method I mentioned would require an e-mail address that has smtp support. There was no need for a sim with what I was talking about. But if you still want an example let me know. @Vikram

Comment: Actually....by any way,I just want to implement sms sending as per my client's requirement.
After trying with lots of API's i came to sms sending by sim card connected to application (pc)...please suggest me what should i do to implement sms sending now?

Comment: @Vikram check my answer I've added some code that I used for a previous project